# Can I turn one gtalk account into invsible and leave other visible in pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, google-talk, jabber

I'm currently using pidgin with multiply gtalk accounts and I want for part of my account to be in invisible mode while leaving other into visible one. Is it possible to do with pidgin?

Answer (score 0):

yes. https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/8053 
"This is possible via the statusbox by selecting 'New status' and then click 'Use a different status for some accounts' or by use of the mystatusbox plugin in the Purple Plugin Pack."

Edit:
For me (pidgin 2.10.7 from ubuntu package) this works as follows: click the status bar at the bottom of the friend list -> New Status -> Status: Invisible -> Use a different status for some accounts.
Although there seems indeed to be a bug, I can only set it to mostly invisible and check "Different" for the non-invisible ones, not the other way around.

However, note whether there is an invisibility feature in the first place depends on the protocols you are using. See
https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/5828

http://www.madhusudancs.info/invisible

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/02/pidgin-plugin-that-enables-invisible.html

for XMPP (g talk, FB, ...)

Comment: It is interesting, that I don't see invisibility as choice of status neither with 'New status' nor with mystatusbox.